# pg_dump can't find existing table

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump

I'm trying to dump only 1 table from database but I'm getting the following error:

> pg_dump: error: no matching tables were found

This is my command:

```
pg_dump --section=data --clean --host $db_url --port $port --user $user $db_name -n $schema --table "customer" --file=data.dump
```

Comment: When the database shows me an error message, I am inclined to believe it.

Comment: Then something must be wrong with my command because I'm connected to the db in datagrip and I can see the table.

Comment: Change `pg_dump` to `echo` so that you can see if all those variables got interpolated the way you want.  Do the real schema or table names have any "weird" characters in them?

Comment: Is the table name actually exactly `customer`? In other words not upper or mixed case?

Comment: FYI, you can shorten this `--section=data --clean` to `-a` or `--data-only`.

Comment: I double checked the table name and it is exactly "customer".

Comment: Then you are not connecting to the database you think you are.  Another FYI, `-n` is ignored when you use `-t`.

Comment: Another thought is to try `--table customer` on the chance the name has leading or trailing empty space not caught by the quoting. A further way to check would be: `select relname, length(relname) from pg_class where trim(relname) = 'customer' ;`